# How to introduce liquibase in midle of spring boot maven based project

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

`I have already running project and trying to introduce liquibase in middle of project.
This is spring boot maven based project.

I am following steps.

1.liquibase.properties

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cc
username=postgres
password=deadline123
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
runOnChange=true
referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cc
referenceUsername=postgres
referencePassword=deadline123
changelogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/diff.yaml
```

1. Run command to generate changelog for current DB state
   `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog`
2. Then run command to sync changelog and create entry in DB
   `mvn liquibase:changelogSync`
3. Starting my application but it's throwing error relation already exist. I can't figure out why liquibase is executing already executed changeset? I am using liquibase 4.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with file path `src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`

`liquibase:changelogSync` adds file path as above in log sync and `liquibae` on start actually takes `classpath` `classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`

Comment: How can we fix this error if we don't use preconditions?

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase doesn't compare changes against your actual tables, it only keeps track of what changesets have already been executed (it creates another table for that called `databasechangelog`).

That being said, you have to make sure liquibase executes your changesets with a precondition that says 'if anything fails, mark it as executed'. It can be achieved like so:

```
<preconditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
        <tableExists tableName="person"/>
    </not>
</preconditions>
```

This example as well as much more information could be found on https://www.liquibase.com/blog/adding-liquibase-on-an-existing-project